# How to show only a subset of labels on x-axis?

Tags: r, plot, graphics, time-series

I am making a plot in R (not ggplot, just basic R), and I set the custom x-axis values using the following code:

```r
plot(my_vector, level=1, labels = F, col = c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "black"), xaxt='n')

axis(1, at=1:length(date_tot), labels=format(as.Date(date_tot, "%Y-%m-%d"), "%d-%m"), las=2, tick=F)

legend(x="topright", col=c("red", "green", "blue", "orange", "black"), legend=my_names, lwd=2, bty='n')
```

The output is like the following:

[image]

Since the x-axis is not well-formatted, I would like to:

1. show only a subset of dates (eg. one every three)
2. move the labels of the x-axis out of the plot (so a bit down)

How can I do so?

Comment: You are explicitly doing that with `1:length(date_tot)`. Instead, create a vector with that, then `vec[seq_along(vec) %% 3 == 0]` will give you every third element. Same for the labels. (I'd demonstrate with your real plot but we don't have your data.)

Comment: Perhaps `vec <- seq_along(date_tot); ind <- ind[ ind %% 3 == 0 ];`, now just add `[ind]` to each of your `at=` and `labels=` vectors.

Comment: yes, you are right. It works. Do you have any suggestion for the second question?

Comment: Is there a reason you are preserving a categorical x-axis? The fact that they represent dates doesn't mean anything differently, if any of your gaps are other than 4 days apart, then the plot will not show a proportionate span of the actual date difference. (Also, it might produce a more intuitive and R-idiomatic axis tick placement.)

Comment: no, it is not mandatory to use categorical labels

Comment: I suggest you convert your `date_tot` to a `Date` object *before* plotting, since it's a continuous variable. You will still likely need to mess with `axis` if you want other than the default date format (which means it is not changing the need for this question), but it's a better way to view continuous data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample:

```r
y <- mtcars$disp
plot(y, pch = 16, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, seq_along(y), las = 2)
```

[image: x-axis too busy]

```r
ind <- seq_along(y)
ind <- ind[ ind %% 3 == 0 ]
ind
#  [1]  3  6  9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
plot(y, pch = 16, xaxt = "n")
axis(1, at = seq_along(y)[ind])
```

[image: relaxed x-axis]

As to your second question, I cannot reproduce it ... perhaps you've adjusted `par` somewhere else in a way that affects margins and such. (Perhaps close and reopen your graphic device ... `dev.off()`?)